# How to find the output shares of first-order threshold implementation of cubic degree function?

Tags: implementation, side-channel-attack

Assume $d=abc$ and  to implement first order threshold implementation , the minimum input and output  shares   are 4 (1*3+1) ,  and  4 , calculated using  ${4\choose 3}$ , [Theorem 2](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-2474.pdf). The new TI equation is:
$$d_{0,1,2,3}= 
(a_0 \oplus a_1 \oplus a_2 \oplus a_3)(b_0 \oplus b_1 \oplus b_2 \oplus b_3)(c_0 \oplus c_1 \oplus c_2 \oplus c_3)$$

breaking out the multiplication results in 64 terms , divinding the terms on 4 output shares , each share will have 16 terms , but how to select the terms for each share?

**Q.** How do you find  the output shares ($d_0$,$d_1$,$d_2$,$d_3$)  equations that acheive non-complete , uniform and correctness features ?

Comment: Could you manage to find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately No